# SQL Server : Insert into Where Condition is True

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data into a table if a condition is true. Here is my pseudo code:

```
INSERT INTO Table1  (BatchStart, BatchId, FermNum,SiteId) 
VALUES (11/11/2016,7280,1,6)
WHERE BatchId > (SELECT TOP 1 BatchId 
                 FROM Table1 
                 ORDER BY BatchStart DESC);
```

I cannot have variables, it must be a plain insert into statement. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use `select` instead of `values`, add names to the columns, and it should work; in this case, inserting either 0 rows or 1 row.

Comment: Why are you checking if the `batchId` is _less_ than everything else?  Do you just need a unique value, something that should be enforced by a unique key?  Do you need a no-gap sequence (note - this is **really** rare)?  Do `batchId`s have to have an order matching `batchStart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid on sql server.

```
INSERT INTO Table1  (BatchStart, BatchId, FermNum,SiteId)  
select '2016-11-11',7280,1,6 
where 7280 > (select top 1 batch_id 
                 FROM Table1 
                 ORDER BY BatchStart DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
INSERT INTO Table1  (BatchStart, BatchId, FermNum,SiteId) 
SELECT '20161111',MAX(BTACHID) +1 ,1,6 From Table1
```

There are many way to insert data. Read this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx) for more info

Comment: `MAX(someColumn) + 1` is usually a terrible idea, because it requires exclusively locking the entire table to deal with concurrent writes.  Depending on how long you hold such a lock, it could end poorly (or not end, as it were).  It's unclear if the OP actually needs a gapless sequence, too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SELECT` to get all the necessary data, then insert into the table.

```
INSERT INTO Table1  (BatchStart, BatchId, FermNum,SiteId) 
SELECT '11-11-2016','7280','1','6'
WHERE BatchId > (SELECT TOP 1 BatchId 
                 FROM Table1 
                 ORDER BY BatchStart DESC);
```